# How can I implement a typed/typesafe iterator?

Tags: php, php-7, type-safety

I have code that looks like this, which I'd like to improve:

```
// example type
class Stuff
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

// generator function
function searchStuff()
{
    yield new Stuff('Fou');
    yield new Stuff('Barre');
    yield new Stuff('Bazze');
}

// code that iterates over the results of the generator
$stuffIterator = searchStuff();
assert($stuffIterator instanceof Iterator);
foreach ($stuffIterator as $stuff) {
    /** @var Stuff $stuff */
    echo $stuff->getName() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The thing that I'd like to improve is the annotation in the loop (third last line), which I'd like to remove completely. The reasons are

- it should be unnecessary with proper type hints that are even enforced by the language
- it may or may not reflect reality, i.e. it is prone to break on code changes
- it is unnecessary work typing it and, even worse, reading it.

My naïve approach was to declare an iterator interface that adds a proper type annotation to the generic `Iterator` interface:

```
interface StuffIterator extends Iterator
{
    public function current(): Stuff;
}
```

This has the drawback that I can't set this as "hard" annotation on the function, only as docstring annotation, because `"Generators may only declare a return type of Generator, Iterator, Traversable, or iterable"`, which is bad, because then it isn't enforced. Further, my IDE doesn't pick up the type, but that's a different issue.

A different approach was to write an actual iterator class that wraps the `Generator` returned from the function. Problem there is that this class needs to be instantiated as well, so I would have to call `$stuffGenerator = new StuffIterator(searchStuff());` or write another wrapper function to do that, neither of which should be necessary. Still, the stupid IDE doesn't pick up the type hint (grrrr...!).

So, here's my question: What alternatives exist to this approach? I'd imagine something like C++ or Java generics, but alas, I can't simply rewrite the application in question.

Further notes:

- The example code works, that's not the problem, my concerns are rather maintainability, readability and elegance.
- I can't simply return an array, using a generator at this point is important. So, any suggestion based on this approach is not a solution.
- I'm using PHP 7.1 at the moment, but I don't rule out upgrading. I'd consider an answer valid if it required upgrading, too.

Answer (score 2):

a very good question. I guess the answer to your question will not turn out as you might expect. The solution is perhaps not nice, but works. First of all you can not define a yield return type other than `Generator` and so on. You have given the answer yourself. But ...

Just image the following starting point.

```
class Stuff
{
    protected $name;

    public function getName() : ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name) : Stuff
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

class StuffCollection extends \IteratorIterator
{
    public function __construct(Stuff ...$items)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            (function() use ($items) {
                yield from $items;
            })()
        );
    }

    public function current() : Stuff
    {
        return parent::current();
    }
}
```

What I 've done here? We know the `Stuff` class already. It does nothing new. The new thing is the `StuffCollection` class. Because of extending it from the `IteratorIterator` class we can override the `IteratorIterator::current()` method and give it a type hint.

```
$collection = new StuffCollection(
    (new Stuff())->setName('One'),
    (new Stuff())->setName('Two'),
    (new Stuff())->setName('Three')
);

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    var_dump(assert($item instance of Stuff));
    echo sprintf(
        'Class: %s. Calling getName method returns "%s" (%s)',
        get_class($item),
        $item->getName(),
        gettype($item->getName())
    ) . "<br>";
}
```

The output from that should be ...

```
bool(true) Class: Stuff. Calling getName method returns "One" (string)
bool(true) Class: Stuff. Calling getName method returns "Two" (string)
bool(true) Class: Stuff. Calling getName method returns "Three" (string)
```

What does that mean? You really can not define the return type directly in a yield call. A yield will always return a `Generator` instance. One possible solution could be the use of the `IteratorIterator` class.

Even your IDE should work with that solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best solution. My IDE doesn't pick up the type hint, but that's just its problem, maybe I need to upgrade finally. BTW: I mentioned I couldn't return an array, which you ignored. However, it's not even important, because I can wrap both a `Generator` or an array with your approach. In that case, the `StuffIterator` just extends the `IteratorIterator` baseclass and the only method it defines is `current()`, where it adds the type annotation and delegates to the baseclass.